# Getting started with Silex

Tags: php, silex

I am getting to grips with Silex Routing, a simple app displaying various pages.

I am able to register the  ->get('/') route which returns "Hello World", however I when I run ->get('/hello/{name}') I run into a Object not found 404 Error.

Multiple tutorials and advice insist I do it this way however do I not need to register the route first?

```
<?php

/* include the silex autoload */
require_once __DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php';

$app = new Silex\Application();

$app['debug'] = true;

/* silex uses anonymous functions to define routes */
$app->get('/', function() use($app) {

return 'Hello World!';

});

$app->get('/hello/{name}', function($name) use($app) {

return 'Hello '.$app->escape($name);
});

$app->run();
```

I have also tried

```
$app->get("/hello/{name}", function($name){
  return 'Hello '.$name;
});
```

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: Silex usually ships without .htaccess. Have you tried adding `index.php` to your URL - `/index.php/hello/jmack` or have I not understood your question correctly?

Comment: Which URL are you asking for (type the absolute URL *http:/ /server.com/...*)?

Comment: Thank you Artamiel I was missing index.php off my URL, add it as a answer and I will accept it! Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I said in my comment, `Silex` usually ships without .htaccess file, so all requests must include `index.php` in URL in order for the routing to work.

That of course doesn't mean that you can't create the .htaccess file by yourself. In fact, there is a chapter about server configurations in Silex documentation, providing a simple .htaccess config. Link to chapter - [Webserver Configuration.](http://silex.sensiolabs.org/doc/web_servers.html#webserver-configuration)

I'll copy the code here for future requests:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options -MultiViews

    RewriteEngine On
    #RewriteBase /path/to/app
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [QSA,L]
</IfModule>
```

And a note about `RewriteBase`:

> If your site is not at the webroot level you will have to uncomment the RewriteBase statement and adjust the path to point to your directory, relative from the webroot.